# Attempting to return users registered per month, but not getting a correct count in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am attempting to fetch a count of users who have registered each month, separated by month in the results - so, January - 22, February - 36, March- 56, so on and so forth limited to this month and the last five.

However, I can't seem to get the query correct as it relates to CakePHP 3's query builder. This is what I have so far:

```
$query = $this->find('all');
$query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('id'), 'day' => 'DAY(dateRegistered)']);
$query->where(['YEAR(dateRegistered)' => date('Y')]);
$query->group(['MONTH(dateRegistered)']);       
$query->enableHydration(false);
return $query->all();
```

This seems to return the user count for the month, but that's all, and not in an easily graph-able format. I have seen some queries in raw SQL so it should be possible, but I would like to use the native query controls in Cake. Could someone help fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you select the month instead of the day (that wouldn't won't work well anyways, MySQL would pick an unpredictable value from the group, if it doesn't error out that is)? And what exactly do you mean by "_easily graph-able format_"? What do you expect the result set to look like?

Comment: At very least, I'm looking for a array return I can graph to months. I don't expect the query itself to return the month count

Comment: Did you try @ndm's suggestion of selecting the month instead of the day? Seems that would give you exactly what you want: a set of months and the count for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->find();

    $res = $query
            ->select([
                'month'=>'monthname(created)',
                'count'=>$query->func()->count('*'),
            ])
            ->where('year(created) = year(curdate())')
            ->group('month')
            ->enableHydration(false);

    pr($res->toArray());
```